# Want to restore the postgres database on Cloud SQL using a sql file dump which is of 110GB and stored in the Google cloud storage

Tags: linux, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, cloud

I am trying to restore the postgres database that I have setup on a Google Cloud SQL server and the backup file that I have created using pg_dump with custom format is stored in Cloud Storage in the bucket and of size around 110 GB. I have tested my restore command when the file is in the same directory in my postgres instance but it is not working whenever I am passing it using the gs url of the bucket. I have also tried to copy the file from bucket to directory but it is not working as there is not enough space even if I have allocated 300GB of SSD to the postgres instance.
The command I am using to restore is for Directory that is working command:

```
pg_restore --verbose --no-acl --no-owner -Fc --host 35.231.137.82 --port 5432 --dbname=IDXGenerator_prod --username=postgres march_10_2022.sql_.gstmp
```

For Bucket url that is not working is :

```
pg_restore --verbose --no-acl --no-owner -Fc --host 35.231.137.82 --port 5432 --dbname=IDXGenerator_prod --username=postgres gs://sqltransferlargefile/march_10_2022.sql
```

Any suggestion or help is needed so that it can work from the cloud storage.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/596kz.png)

Comment: The error clearly says you don’t have enough space on the device. Also the output of df -h does not show a 300GB sized disk? Also when you export the database (pg_dump) are you compressing the output file?

Comment: Thanks for your answer , I agree with your point and that's what I have mentioned that increasing the storage would not help much so I need if there is a way so that I can restore it by providing details from cloud storage bucket. Yes when I have backup the database I have used level 9 (maximum) compression with custom format